# Convert dc.js chart to pdf

Tags: pdf, d3.js, dc.js

I am using dc.js to create charts. I want to export the charts as pdf. Seems like converting to SVG and then using perl scripts to convert SVG to pdf is the only way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm on a Mac so, the easiest option there is to print and save as PDF. I believe on Windows there are several options for PDF print drivers. Would that work for you? You could export the SVG, but you'll lose any CSS styling you have, so it's often less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks but I need to create the pdf programatically so that people can click a button and download pdf

Comment: I've use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to do this on past projects.

Comment: Why the downvotes. This is an important question.

Comment: Yeah, then I'd agree with Mark - just working with the SVG directly probably isn't going to work because you'll lose formatting, so you need to render the chart in a page. http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html is specifically what you probably want.

Comment: @Gordon I don't get it either. Would be good if we could flag votes as being incorrect :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method using Inkscape (on server):

js:

```
// --- create your chart before this ---   
postdata = {
    'url':CryptoJS.MD5(window.location.href).toString(),   
    //used to name the file based on its url (used for caching, containing parameters in my case)
    'svg':$('#chart').html()
    //the created svg chart (using jQuery here)
};
$.post('create_pdf.php',postdata);
//POST the svg to php (using jQuery here)
```

create_pdf.php:

```
//save the svg file as XYZ.svg
file_put_contents($_POST['url'] . '.svg',$_POST['svg']);
// run the command: inkscape -z XYZ.svg -A XYZ.pdf
// for png would do: inkscape -z XYZ.svg -e XYZ.png
$com = 'inkscape -z ' . $_POST['url'] . '.svg -A ' .  $_POST['url'] . '.pdf';
exec($com);
```

note: I use d3.js directly, not dc.js (not sure about that)